# Laravel Permission and Role not working with Can

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, laravel-blade, role

I'm working on an app which has several privileges, but when I tried to use @can and @endcan the app will not show the link for all users. help?

This is my `.blade`

```
@can('read.account')<li><a href="{{ route('Account.index') }}">Accounts</a></li>@endcan
```

my `AuthServiceProvider.php`

public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

```
    if(Schema::hasTable('permissions')){
        $permissions = Permission::all();
        foreach($permissions as $permission) {
            $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) use ($permission) {
                return $permission;
            });
        }
    }


}
```

and my seed

```
$superadmin->addPermission('read.account');
$superadmin->addPermission('read.customer');
$admin->addPermission('read.customer');
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you use any package for role & permission ?

Comment: use this https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust